# How can I get all rows whos timestamp is closest to midnight (sampling timeseries)

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table that counts the amount of user interaction with a given item.  Basically it has a table with 3 rows (item_name, time, num_interactions).  The number of interactions never decreases, it counts all interactions that have ever happened (this is done so it can be sampled at every interval and doesn't need to be summed up).

It will sum up and and add the interactions every 15 minutes, for 96 records every day. (the way it works it upserts to the current 15 minute slot on every interaction request from the client, but that doesn't really matter)

Now I would like to visualize this data in a statistics view that can display the amount of interactions over time with a given item `daily`, `monthly` and over `all time`.

Now `daily` is easy. I simply "WHERE" all the records inbetween now and 24 hours ago. But with `montly` and `all time` it gets tricky. I only want to return every midnight row for `monthly` and a total amount of 100 evenly spaced rows for `all time` to the client to draw the graph.

At least with `monthly` I thought could just return every 96th row like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY time DESC) AS row
  FROM stats
) t
WHERE t.row % 96 = 0
```

The only problem with that is that the server might shut down sometimes and some timestamps may not be recorded, leading to some samples being recorded at different times of day.

With `all time`, I could just replace 96 with the total number of rows divided by 100, but even then sampling from different times of day may falsify the statstic.

Long story short, I need a query that returns to me every row of a given day that is closest to midnight of the next day.

Comment: If interactions never decreases, then you can use max() to get the end of day value, and group by date_trunc(‘day’, …). For all time you can use generate_series() and join to it. If they don’t have to be evenly spaced you can do a random sample.

Comment: if I use max, wont I have terrible performance, since it would basically need to scan the whole table every time a user sends a request?

Comment: `some timestamps may not be recorded`. What's the rough percentage of missing rows if you pick every "midnight"? Also, please provide the basics: Postgres version, table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), sample data, desired result.